# ExpandableListView inside NavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I'm currently developing an Android application what I need is to implement a ExpandableListView for single fragment of Navigation Drawer List. 
I already implemented the Navigation Drawer from this tutorial:
https://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial

Now I have my Navigation Drawer consist of 3 fragments. Fragment A, Fragment B, Fragment C.Here my question is While clicking **Fragment A** of drawer list it have to be expandable with two sub items.
So,on **Fragment A** how can I add  ExpandableListView for that Fragment only? How do I accomplish it?please anyone can help me..

Comment: did you mean you want implement expandable listview Fragment A only?

Comment: yes,for fragment A only I want to implement expandablelistview.

Comment: okay you can set fragment layout from expandable listview item click you should  create 3 different layout for 3 fragments

Comment: I did n't get u sir..

Comment: post your snippet code  for changing fragment

Comment: I did n't made any changes for above link because i don't know how to do expandablelistview for only one  Fragment in navigation view

Comment: Anu, may i know where you need expandable listview, you need in inside fragment or in drawer menu? .

Comment: inside drawer menu

Comment: @AnuCute , see this link if you want like this  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hj1Tv53ffQntihls547TtwFviSVmoSeP

Answer (score 0):

[implementing Expandable ListView using Fragments please check](http://pavantilak.blogspot.com/2012/12/best-code-of-implementing-expandable.html)